# this core plot code is working on iphone but not on ipad

Tags: ios, ios5, charts, ios6, core-plot

This core plot is created from : http://codejunkster.wordpress.com/2011/11/23/core-plot-2-bar-plot/#comment-85  . I have created 2 app with the same code, one for iPhone and another for iPad.The iphone app works perfectly but the ipad app displays x-coordinates and y-coordinated along with the title not the columns I don’t have any idea how to fix it.Please help me.It would be a great help.Using Xcode 4.5.2 ios6 .Thanks in Advance.

BarPlotViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h"

@interface BarPlotViewController : UIViewController
<CPTBarPlotDataSource, CPTBarPlotDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *data;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CPTGraphHostingView *hostingView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CPTXYGraph *graph;

- (void) generateBarPlot;

@end
```

BarPlotViewController.m

```
#import "BarPlotViewController.h"

@interface BarPlotViewController ()

@end

@implementation BarPlotViewController

#define BAR_POSITION @"POSITION"
#define BAR_HEIGHT @"HEIGHT"
#define COLOR @"COLOR"
#define CATEGORY @"CATEGORY"

#define AXIS_START 0
#define AXIS_END 50

@synthesize data;
@synthesize graph;
@synthesize hostingView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

        self.data = [NSMutableArray array];

        int bar_heights[] = {20,30,10,40};
        UIColor *colors[] = {
            [UIColor redColor],
            [UIColor blueColor],
            [UIColor orangeColor],
            [UIColor purpleColor]};
        NSString *categories[] = {@"Plain Milk", @"Milk + Caramel", @"White", @"Dark"};

        for (int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++){
            double position = i*10; //Bars will be 10 pts away from each other
            double height = bar_heights[i];

            NSDictionary *bar = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 [NSNumber numberWithDouble:position],BAR_POSITION,
                                 [NSNumber numberWithDouble:height],BAR_HEIGHT,
                                 colors[i],COLOR,
                                 categories[i],CATEGORY,
                                 nil];
            [self.data addObject:bar];

        }
        [self generateBarPlot];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)generateBarPlot
{
    //Create host view
    self.hostingView = [[CPTGraphHostingView alloc]
                        initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]];
    [self.view addSubview:self.hostingView];

    //Create graph and set it as host view's graph
    self.graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.hostingView.bounds];
    [self.hostingView setHostedGraph:self.graph];

    //set graph padding and theme
    self.graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingTop = 20.0f;
    self.graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingRight = 20.0f;
    self.graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom = 70.0f;
    self.graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft = 70.0f;
    [self.graph applyTheme:[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTDarkGradientTheme]];

    //set axes ranges
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)self.graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:
                        CPTDecimalFromFloat(AXIS_START)
                                                    length:CPTDecimalFromFloat((AXIS_END - AXIS_START)+5)];
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:
                        CPTDecimalFromFloat(AXIS_START)
                                                    length:CPTDecimalFromFloat((AXIS_END - AXIS_START)+5)];

    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)self.graph.axisSet;
    //set axes' title, labels and their text styles
    CPTMutableTextStyle *textStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    textStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica";
    textStyle.fontSize = 14;
    textStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    axisSet.xAxis.title = @"CHOCOLATE";
    axisSet.yAxis.title = @"AWESOMENESS";
    axisSet.xAxis.titleTextStyle = textStyle;
    axisSet.yAxis.titleTextStyle = textStyle;
    axisSet.xAxis.titleOffset = 30.0f;
    axisSet.yAxis.titleOffset = 40.0f;
    axisSet.xAxis.labelTextStyle = textStyle;
    axisSet.xAxis.labelOffset = 3.0f;
    axisSet.yAxis.labelTextStyle = textStyle;
    axisSet.yAxis.labelOffset = 3.0f;
    //set axes' line styles and interval ticks
    CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    lineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    lineStyle.lineWidth = 3.0f;
    axisSet.xAxis.axisLineStyle = lineStyle;
    axisSet.yAxis.axisLineStyle = lineStyle;
    axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
    axisSet.yAxis.majorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
    axisSet.xAxis.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromFloat(5.0f);
    axisSet.yAxis.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromFloat(5.0f);
    axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLength = 7.0f;
    axisSet.yAxis.majorTickLength = 7.0f;
    axisSet.xAxis.minorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
    axisSet.yAxis.minorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
    axisSet.xAxis.minorTicksPerInterval = 1;
    axisSet.yAxis.minorTicksPerInterval = 1;
    axisSet.xAxis.minorTickLength = 5.0f;
    axisSet.yAxis.minorTickLength = 5.0f;

    // Create bar plot and add it to the graph
    CPTBarPlot *plot = [[CPTBarPlot alloc] init] ;
    plot.dataSource = self;
    plot.delegate = self;
    plot.barWidth = [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"5.0"]
                     decimalValue];
    plot.barOffset = [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"10.0"]
                      decimalValue];
    plot.barCornerRadius = 5.0;
    // Remove bar outlines
    CPTMutableLineStyle *borderLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    borderLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor clearColor];
    plot.lineStyle = borderLineStyle;
    // Identifiers are handy if you want multiple plots in one graph
    plot.identifier = @"chocoplot";
    [self.graph addPlot:plot];

}

-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot
{
    if ( [plot.identifier isEqual:@"chocoplot"] )
        return [self.data count];

    return 0;
}


-(CPTLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if ( [plot.identifier isEqual: @"chocoplot"] )
    {
        CPTMutableTextStyle *textStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
        textStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica";
        textStyle.fontSize = 14;
        textStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];

        NSDictionary *bar = [self.data objectAtIndex:index];
        CPTTextLayer *label = [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [bar valueForKey:@"CATEGORY"]]];
        label.textStyle =textStyle;

        return label;
    }

    CPTTextLayer *defaultLabel = [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:@"Label"];
    return defaultLabel;

}


-(CPTFill *)barFillForBarPlot:(CPTBarPlot *)barPlot
                  recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if ( [barPlot.identifier isEqual:@"chocoplot"] )
    {
        NSDictionary *bar = [self.data objectAtIndex:index];
        CPTGradient *gradient = [CPTGradient gradientWithBeginningColor:[CPTColor whiteColor]
                                                            endingColor:[bar valueForKey:@"COLOR"]
                                                      beginningPosition:0.0 endingPosition:0.3 ];
        [gradient setGradientType:CPTGradientTypeAxial];
        [gradient setAngle:320.0];

        CPTFill *fill = [CPTFill fillWithGradient:gradient];

        return fill;

    }
    return [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0]];

}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "BarPlotViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) BarPlotViewController *barPlotViewController;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize barPlotViewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    barPlotViewController = [[BarPlotViewController alloc] init];
    [self.window setRootViewController:barPlotViewController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
@end
```

Image of the Simulator on Ipad:  [image]

This is how it looks on iphone same code : [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your datasource needs to implement one of the following methods:

```
-(NSArray *)numbersForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot
                     field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum
          recordIndexRange:(NSRange)indexRange;

-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot
                     field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum
               recordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx;

-(double *)doublesForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot
                    field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum
         recordIndexRange:(NSRange)indexRange;

-(double)doubleForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot
                 field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum
           recordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx;

-(CPTNumericData *)dataForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot
                         field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum
              recordIndexRange:(NSRange)indexRange;

-(CPTNumericData *)dataForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot
              recordIndexRange:(NSRange)indexRange;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What am I supposed to replace in the following code or WHat will the final code look like in the above example.Please modify the above code ,I am still confused.Thanks in Advance Eric.And Why did it work in iphone then?

Comment: I don't know how your app would work on any platform without one of these methods. Look at any of the Core Plot example apps for sample code. `-numberForPlot:field:recordIndex:` is most common in the examples. The proper choice depends on how your data is stored in the model.

Comment: Thanks for getting back .I have updated the images for my question above please look into it and tell me where/what the problem is? I have tried everything from last 1 week but I am stuck as there no good tutorial for core-plot customization and this is sort of urgent requirement.Thanks again Eric.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed all the settings to iPad except the targets --> Device --> iPad .And then it started to work.This has been the worst mistake ever and an awful waste of Time.